# How to Create a Colourful Table in HTML

Tags: html, blogs

I have a blog on Wordpress and I want to create a stylish colourful table on my blog please. Suggest me code for my [blog](http://www.banshidharinfo.com)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex pointed out, the material color palette is a modern and nice way to get colors. All you would need to do is apply it to the different segments of your table.

```css
.myTable {
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f44336;
  
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Header */
.myTable thead th {
  background: #f44336;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3em 1em 1em 1em;
  
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: left;
}
.myTable thead th:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: 600;
}

/* Rows */
.myTable tbody tr td {
  padding: 1em;
}
.myTable tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #ffcdd2;
}
.myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row 1</th>
      <th>Row 2</th>
      <th colspan="2">Row 3 and 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1,1</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>1,3</td>
      <td>1,4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>2,2</td>
      <td>2,3</td>
      <td>2,4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3,1</td>
      <td>3,2</td>
      <td>3,3</td>
      <td>3,4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4,1</td>
      <td>4,2</td>
      <td>4,3</td>
      <td>4,4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```